# CRC32 bruteforce, reversing,

Tags: reverse-engineering, brute-force, crc32, cracking

For an internet challenge I need to try to get the password. But for the moment I'm stuck.

What is the best way to get the value of bigString where `crc32(bigString) == 0xFFFFFFFF`? (0xFFFFFFFF is not the real value, I want to calculate it myself and not spoil the fun for the other people who are trying the challenge)

The things you already know is bigString is a combination of 3 passwords: password1 (32 hexadecimal chars) + password2 (32 hexadecimal chars) + password3  (40 hexadecimal chars). So you know bigString is 104 chars long with the only possible values "0123456789ABCDEF".

Reversing is impossible and just bruteforcing seems almost impossible because it has 104 chars. What are the other possibilities?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your challenge, but I can answer:

> What is the best way to get the value of bigString where
>   crc32(bigString) == 0xFFFFFFFF ?

First off, you should realize that unless "bigString" is only 32 bits, there is more than one solution to that equation.  Depending on how many bits more than 32 there are in bigString, the number of solutions grow exponentially with the number of bits.

My [spoof.c](https://github.com/madler/spoof) code solves that equation directly.  You give it the exclusive-or of the CRC of the string you have with the CRC you want, the length of the message, and the bit locations in the message that you are permitting to be changed.  For a CRC-*n*, there needs to be at least *n* such bit locations provided.  Ideally more than that should be provided to increase the probability of finding a solution.  spoof.c will then tell you which of those bits to invert to give you the desired CRC.